# Can I still use Gmail if Google is blocked by OpenDNS?

Tags: email, dns, gmail, email-client, opendns

OpenDNS blocks access to all search engines, including Google, on my network. I don't necessarily need to search Google, but it would be nice if I could access Gmail still.

If it's not possible to do in the browser, can I still access Gmail some other way? What if I set up a separate email client like Thunderbird? Is that controlled by OpenDNS too?

My only other idea is set up an email address on another email service, like outlook.com or something, then have Gmail forward everything to that.

Comment: OpenDNS blocks search engines? News to me as our company uses it as our primary DNS provider. You've got some sort of misconfiguration or IT inspired lockout elsewhere.

Comment: Rephrase: OpenDNS is configured to block search engines.

Comment: Yuck! Don't want to know the logic behind that.

Comment: Doesn't sound very open to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OpenDNS has been configured to put a block on using **Google.com**, then you run into a massive problem as you will not be able to resolve any Google address including **mail.google.com**.

Any access to Gmail will then either have to be extranet through a device you control that can get access outside the protected network, or to have gmail forward everything to a service you can access internally. It's one reason smart-phones have gained popularity.

Using another client like Thunderbird will not take care of the problem if **pop.gmail.com** and **smtp.gmail.com** are blocked. You still have to access the Google mail servers and the block is on resolving Google addresses through DNS.

I think Chris was thinking about another way of doing it. If the DNS doesn't allow resolving the name, then directly use the IP address in the client (Thunderbird, et al.) I've never been forced into doing that, but Thunderbird's free to experiment with.

The only problem with it is that Google often uses multiple addresses that they round-robin so you might have to fiddle with changing the IP addresses every so often. Currently, OpenDNS is reporting the following for **pop.gmail.com** and **smtp.gmail.com**, you'll have to do it outside the block to see what your area returns:

```
C:\Users\xxx>nslookup smtp.gmail.com
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:400e:c01::6c
      173.194.79.108
      173.194.79.109
Aliases:  smtp.gmail.com


C:\Users\xxx>nslookup pop.gmail.com
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    gmail-pop.l.google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:400e:c01::6d
      173.194.79.109
      173.194.79.108
Aliases:  pop.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works: 173.194.34.85  - you have to copy/paste that IP into your web browser's address bar.

OpenDNS only blocks DNS - if anything. You might be blocked by your proxy.